# Check input elements responsively when changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, interactive

I have this code. It obviously calls function when selected element is focused. The function then checks if selected element has length less than 3, and if it does it changes background color of the element.

```
$('#register-form input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
    if ($(this).length < 3) {
      $(this).css('background','#f00');
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that when there are more than 4 characters within input, color still remains. The problem is that it calls function when element is focused. After that, it doesn't check the if statement anymore, as obviosuly function is never called again.

The solution I seek; I want it to check if the IF statement is still legit once the input element value is changed. Or any other smooth way to check IF statements and calls functions in a live time.

**The answer to this question is simple and well known. However, as you answer please provide some information related to this question; *What are the best ways to check various changes in statements lively? What are the best ways to make website 'alive' and respond to any actions immediately?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the error a class and use onkeyup (and change if you wish - which triggers on blur too)

Also test the .val().length instead:

```
<style>
.error { background-color:red }
</style>

$('#register-form input[type="text"]').on("keyup,change",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("error", $(this).val().length < 3);
}).keyup(); // trigger on load
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#register_form input[type="text"]').on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("error", $(this).val().length < 3);
    console.log("error")
  }).keyup(); // initialise in case of reload
});
```

```css
.error {
      color: red
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="register_form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: What will `$(this).length` return i.e. `1`

Comment: Thanks - I missed that. Fixed

Comment: Would you mind to change code a bit to not be on keyup, but to be on event that is triggered when input element is no longer under rule of :focus? (just change 'keyup,change' with 'blur' )

Comment: Feel free to use blur

Comment: My bad. I actually need to use both blur and keyup to make it work right. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/wotapLvz/3/):

```
$('#register-form input[type="text"]').on("focus input", function(){
    $(this).css('background', $(this).val().length < 3 ? '#f00' : '#fff');
});
```

**EDIT**

Personally, I use AngularJS alot for web applications that have alot of these. E.g. you can do this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myValue" ng-style="{'background-color', myValue.length < 3 ? '#f00' : '#fff'}"/>
```